# Doctrine find Number in simple_array field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity `Customer` with an simple_array field `processNumbers`. So in the DB its saved as an comma-separated list for example: `45645,78787,1111`.
Now I want to find an entry with a specific number `processNumber = 1111`.
I want to do it with the query builder, but I only know the direction when I have an array and I search if a DB entry is in it. This direction doesn't work, it says that there is no entry, but it is:

```
$customer = $queryBuilder
            ->select('customer')
            ->from(Customer::class,'customer')
            ->where(":processNumber IN (customer.processNumbers)")
            ->setParameter('processNumber', $processNumber)
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: $processNumber = 1111

Comment: Just a notice: it is not good database design if you have to search/select on array's that are stored into one database field. If it is still possible you should make a new entity ProcessNumbers and make a relation between the parent entity and the new entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql, you can use the Regex Expression in the [DoctrineExtension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                regexp: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Regexp
```

Then use the regex

```
$qb->andWhere('REGEXP(customer.processNumbers, :regexp) = true')
          ->setParameter('regexp', '(^1111,)|(,1111,)|(,1111$)|(^1111$)')
```

My regex is very basic but understable (well I hope). You can see the regex matching here: https://regex101.com/r/oNqpUf/1

Comment: It's been a while but for anyone, you can use `FIND_IN_SET` instead. It is also included in DoctrineExtension.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
$qb->andWhere("customer.processNumbers LIKE :key1 OR customer.processNumbers LIKE :key2 OR customer.processNumbers LIKE :key3 OR customer.processNumbers LIKE :key4");
$qb->setParameter("key", "1111");
$qb->setParameter("key2", "%,1111");
$qb->setParameter("key3", "1111,%");
$qb->setParameter("key4", "%,1111,%");
```